# Modal Register form is not working

Tags: chaos-tool-suite, javascript

I am using the [Modal forms (with ctools)](https://drupal.org/project/modal_forms) module for registration and login in my Drupal 7 site.

When I click login/register, I am able to log in with an already existing username, but I am not able to create a new account. When I enter the registration details and create the account, nothing happens.

What is wrong with this?